# move div with CSS transition

Tags: html, css

I am using following code to display a hidden div on hover. I'm using the CSS `transition` property for to fade in the hidden div. Is it possible to slide in the hidden (for example from left to right) div instead of fading in using the CSS only?
Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8207/8275533487_5ebe5826ee.jpg"></a>
    <div class="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
    position: relative;    
}

.box .hidden{    
   background: yellow;
    height: 300px;    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;    
    width: 500px;
    opacity: 0;    
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.box:hover .hidden{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/u2FKM/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Something like this?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u2FKM/4/)

And the code I used:

```
.box{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box:hover .hidden{

    left: 0px;
}

.box .hidden {    
    background: yellow;
    height: 300px;    
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: -500px;    
    width: 500px;
    opacity: 1;    
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
            transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
```

I may also add that it's possible to move an elment using `transform: translate();` , which in this case could work something like this - [DEMO nr2](http://jsfiddle.net/u2FKM/13/)

Answer (score 4):

Just to add my answer, it seems that the transitions need to be based on initial values and final values within the css properties to be able to manage the animation.

Those reworked css classes should provide the expected result :

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 0px;
}

.box:hover .hidden {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 500px;
}

.box .hidden {
  background: yellow;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8207/8275533487_5ebe5826ee.jpg">
  </a>
  <div class="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u2FKM/2199/

Answer (score 3):

I added the vendor prefixes, and changed the animation to `all`, so you have both opacity and width that are animated.

Is this what you're looking for ? http://jsfiddle.net/u2FKM/3/

Answer (score 2):

```
transition-property:width;
```

This should work. you have to have browser dependent code

Answer (score 1):

This may be the good solution for you: change the code like this very little change

```
.box{
    position: relative; 
}
.box:hover .hidden{
    opacity: 1;
    width:500px;
}
.box .hidden{
    background: yellow;
    height: 334px; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

See [demo here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/u2FKM/11/)