# Mobile nav bar ( no jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been looking around for a while now on how to do this but can't find a good enough answer, I found this jQuery plugin called Sidr: [here](http://www.berriart.com/sidr/)

What I was wondering is is there an easy way in-which to create this same effect with the nav bar coming in from the right hand side but without jQuery?

Comment: Don't tag jQuery if you don't want jQuery

Comment: sorry, stupid mistake

Comment: Why do you not want jQuery?

Comment: no real reason tbh, I just dont want to use a plugin such as this. If you could provide an answer in jquery I would most likely use it though

Comment: @spamy: Check out my answer below :) It just uses 1 line of jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a CSS solution. Works from left and right sides (both). It's awesome:

http://jsfiddle.net/nicooprat/Aahqh/

Just uses 1 line of jQuery for it to work with iOS Safari, just one.

```
$('label').click(function() {});
```

Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at css transitions and animations. Here in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968486/move-div-with-css-transition) the OP is asking for something similair. I felt free to copy the jsFiddle from an answer to this question. Look at it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u2FKM/4/).

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8207/8275533487_5ebe5826ee.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.box:hover .hidden{

    left: 0px;
}

.box .hidden {    
   background: yellow;
    height: 300px;    
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: -500px;    
    width: 500px;
    opacity: 1;    
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
            transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
```