# Can anyone make this dropdown javascript fade in + slide in and fade out +slide out?

Tags: javascript

Yes, I am asking too much, but I have no usable javascript knowledge. The code I used is exactly what you find in w3school dropdown-list demo. Can you please make my dropdown-list fade in, slide in and fade out, slide out. Here it is:

/* When the user clicks on the button,toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it

```
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the [W3school demo link](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar_click). It's pretty much my structure.

Comment: Your link doesn't point to a valid page.

Comment: Your W3 Schools link is 404. Are you using jQuery or straight JavaScript?

Comment: This is harder to do with pure vanilla JS; How about [CSS animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) or jQuery?

Comment: Also, I think the link is meant to be http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar_click (Missing a `?` after `.asp`) but I can't edit since there's one in the queue.

Comment: Try finding out about CSS transitions

Comment: `Can you please make my dropdown-list fade in, slide in and fade out, slide out.` not a problem. I charge £12 per hour and you can hire me for a minimum of 5 hours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [move div with CSS transition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968486/move-div-with-css-transition)

Comment: I have already tried css transitions. But since my dropdown-list works via JS, it is not working. I've fixed the W3 schools link. I don't need it to be pure JS, it can have jQuery. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's fadeIn() and fadeOut() methods this is doable (http://api.jquery.com/fadein/ http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

```
function myFunction() {
      $("#myDropdown").fadeIn();
    //document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      $("#myDropdown").fadeOut();
      /*if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }*/
    }
  }
}

$(function()
{
 $("#btnButton1").click(myFunction);
});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/6ry2c7dn/1/

Comment: Thank you. That was very useful. Only one problem though. Adding the jQuery makes it so you can't close the dropdown by clicking the button. Minor change, but kinda important cause I can't use this. Hoping you could solve it. Thank you anyway.